# android scrollview not working

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I created some XML activity file. I wrote some code. I use scrollview and this scrollview not working.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="#171717" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:background="#171717" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:background="#363636"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latteryresult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circlelayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="click the button"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/circlelayout2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >


    </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

When I click edit text and keyboard  is showing -- then I can't scroll.scrollview not working.
What am I doing wrong? If anyone knows solution please help me.

Comment: There is no ScrollView in your layout.

Comment: @atok scrollview is the root view

Comment: Did you set android:windowSoftInputMode in manifest? It should work with default values but will not if set to "adjustPan".

Comment: @atok no sir i have not.

Comment: Is there a reason why layout_width is set to "wrap_content" ? "match_parent" would be a normal value.

Comment: @atok the `width` can be `wrap_content` that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `RelativeLayout` must have the `android:layout_height` set to `wrap_content`.

Because `match_parent` don't let the view expand more than the height of the (visible) `ScrollView`.

Comment: if i give wrapcontent scroll is working,but my content is getting up.Weight is not working and gravity bottom also not working

Comment: any other solution to get content on the bottom of screen with entair screen need to scroll

Comment: @m.v.n.kalyani can you make a little illustration of what you would like exactly? Because `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in something scroll-able is not very pertinent.

Comment: I want content in scrollview at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Ok, but if you put your content at the bottom, the content is less than the height of the scrollview? Why are you adding a scollview?
I'm sorry, but maybe a screen with the indication of what will be scrolled is a good way for understand. I'm sure that we can find a solution! :)

Comment: You need to use `android:fillViewport` flag on `ScrollView` then the content should be with `wrap_content` and `layout_gravity="bottom"`